# BASH: append loop output to an email

Tags: bash

I want the output of this script to be a body of the email message but I don't want to redirect it to a file first and then to an email, basically no external login/output files - all action should be done within the script itself - is it possible to do it?

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

email() {

        echo "Results:"

}

for i in $(ls -1 test); do

if [ -f "test/$i" ]; then
        echo "'$i' it's a file."
else

        echo "'$i' it's a directory."
fi

done

email | mail -s "Test" an@example.com
```

Output:

```
$ ./tmp.sh 
'd1' it's a directory.
'f1' it's a file.
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to move down the `}` to enclose the for loop as well, to get everything into the mail body.